# need help finding a specific book

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

if anyone knows which book this page is taken from please tell me. thanks !
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ggnqWKLzH8jU8getyoF4&gws_rd=cr&fg=1#q=so+the+Product+rule+(Theorem+10.7.5,+Formula+3)+gives) of:

> so the Product rule (Theorem 10.7.5, Formula 3) gives

Suggests that this from **Section 10.8** of [Essential Calculus: Early Transcendentals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133112285) by James Stewart on **Page 595** (Second Edition).